# Is there a reason why the JavaScript console or WebStorm IDE didn't warn me about this mistake?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Below is some code that wasn't behaving as expected. The `middleLayerChoice` being passed into the function that holds this code is `'2MM'`. Looking at it now, the error is obvious, but this was nested into a longer conditional branch (I'll be refactoring to Switch statements) so it took me a few trial-and-error runs of plugging in some `console.log('line x')` statements. The broken code is below:

```
if (middleLayerChoice === '1MM') 
     if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_1.js');
     }                
     else if (buttonID === 'xmm3mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 3mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_3_1.js');
     }
else if(middleLayerChoice === '2MM') {
     if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 2mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_2.js');
     }
     else if (buttonID === 'xmm3mm') {
          console.log('MID = 2mm, TOP = 3mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_3_2.js'); 
     }
}
...
...
else {
     console.log('getNewObject case 3 failed');
}
```

**What I was missing was an entire set of braces:**

```
if (middleLayerChoice === '1MM') **{**
     if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_1.js');
     }
**}**
```

Once we're all done giggling at my amateur mistake, could anyone tell my why the JavaScript console or WebStorm didn't warn me about this error? My code didn't crash, my `else` statement didn't log the error I wanted, and the code kept on running like things were okay (what was being returned was an `undefined` value).

I feel like compilers from other languages would have screamed at me for this mistake; so what's the reasoning behind both JavaScript *and* WebStorm ignoring this?

Comment: It's not an error, and without those `{ }` it means the same thing anyway. *edit* oh wait, the braces were around more than what you describe. Well, it's still not a syntax error.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about anyone giggling at you, to be honest. This is the kind of JS gotcha that everyone gets tripped up on at one point or another.

Comment: The question was answered, so to address the bonus cookie, `return ("stuff")` is typically written `return "stuff"`, without the parenthesis. Minor nitpick.

Comment: @Pointy It is true that the everything indented under the top `if` works the same with or without brackets, but the problem here (which it took me more than a little while to realize) is that the `else` at the top-level indentation actually applies to the inner `else if`, not the outer `if`

Comment: @apsillers yes, it's the classic `if ... then ... else` grammar ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's technically legit. You can have a one-line statement block. So, that's why the code didn't complain, although that's definitely not what you wanted because this:

```
if (middleLayerChoice === '1MM') 
     if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_1.js');
     }                
     else if (buttonID === 'xmm3mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 3mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_3_1.js');
     }
else if(middleLayerChoice === '2MM') {
     if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 2mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_2.js');
     }
     else if (buttonID === 'xmm3mm') {
          console.log('MID = 2mm, TOP = 3mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_3_2.js'); 
     }
}
...
...
else {
     console.log('getNewObject case 3 failed');
}
```

got interpreted as (note the indentation, added the braces for clarity):

```
if (middleLayerChoice === '1MM') {
     if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_1.js');
     }                
     else if (buttonID === 'xmm3mm') {
          console.log('MID = 1mm, TOP = 3mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_3_1.js');
     }
     else if(middleLayerChoice === '2MM') {
        if (buttonID === 'xmm2mm') {
          console.log('MID = 2mm, TOP = 2mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_2_2.js');
        }
        else if (buttonID === 'xmm3mm') {
          console.log('MID = 2mm, TOP = 3mm');
          return ('resources/OptionalTopCovers/M_3_2.js'); 
        }
     }
     ...
     ...
     else {
         console.log('getNewObject case 3 failed');
     }
}
```

causing only `middleLayerChoice === '1MM'` to actually be able to "go in", to check for `buttonID`.

Many thanks to @apsillers for helping me correct this.

Comment: True, but we have a different situation here, OPs code will fail for `middleLayerChoice === '1MM'` and `buttonID === 'xmm3mm'`, yet it shouldn't. And `middleLayerChoice !== '1MM'` and `buttonID === 'xmm3mm'` would still work unexpected because it would enter the `else` part.

Comment: @apsillers Actually, you're right: `if(false) if(false) { 1; } else if(true) { 2; } // undefined`, and I'd expect `2`.

Comment: @apsillers, thank you, see my update showing that the brackets actually do matter. Consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/tLjqf55n/ - it would ignore `else if(middleLayerChoice === '2MM') {`.

Comment: Aha, the problem here is that the `else` which was *intended* for the outer `if` actually attaches to the inner `if` (and not the other way around; the `else` intended for the inner `if` behaves as expected). Your revised answer looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript `if`s can be followed by a block *or* a statement.

```
if (1)
    doSomething();
else
    doSomethingElse();
doSomethingInEitherCase();
```

… is valid, albeit frowned up, JS.

Tools such as [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) can alert you to syntax which is valid but which suffers from this kind of gotcha.

Comment: Wow, thanks man. That's good to know, I had no clue. Lol that's kind of going to give me nightmares haha. Not that I leave out entire brackets _that_ often, but when it happens, it can be a sucker to find haha.

Comment: @8protons note that every other C-heritage language (at least that I know of) has this same syntactic quirk.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said; there was no error, without the curly-braces the if applies to the statement, with them it applies to the block.

To avoid the problem in the future, you can reformat your code (Ctrl-Alt-L or search for it with Ctrl-Shift-A) Webstorm will automatically change indentation and make it obvious what lines belong to which if-block.

To make the problem even more obvious in the future, you can go into Settings>Editor>Code Style>JavaScript, the tab Wrapping and Braces and change "force braces" to "Always" for if, while, for and do.

Compared to other languages, JavaScript support in Webstorm is worse; *good*, but not on the level of Java or even PHP. Probably because JavaScript is very flexible, not in *any* way statically typed and has lacked oversight for most of it's lifetime. Adding docblocks help a lot.

There are a lot of other tools that help as well, like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) and [TypeScript;](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) but setting them up can be more trouble than it's worth when you are a beginner.